# app = Flask(__name__) TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, flask

When I run the following code, I get `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` instead of a running application.

```
import flask as Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

```
  app = Flask(__name__)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: `Flask.Flask(__name__)` or `from flask import Flask; Flask(__name__)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have aliased the module instead of importing the `Flask` class.

Try instead

`from flask import Flask`

Answer (score 0):

`Flask.Flask(__name__)` worked

Thanks @Wondercricket from the comment section.